# Why am I getting a nonetype error when trying to collect prices from a website?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

This is my code in Jupyter-Lab:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

secure = "https://"
city = input("Type name of city without spaces:")
url = ".craigslist.org/d/for-sale/search/sss?query="
instrument = input("Type name of instrument without spaces:")

for x in page:
    x = 0
    x = x + 1
page = "&s=" + str(120 * x)

z = secure + city + url + instrument + page
y = requests.get(url = y)
htmlread = z.content

bs = BeautifulSoup(htmlread, 'html.parser')

price = bs.findAll('span', 'result-price')
pl = []
for a in price:
    pricelist = a.span.string
    pl.append(pricelist)
print(pl)
```

This is the error I got:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

Comment: As far as I know, the website is being recognized properly, but for some reason, it might not be finding any of the prices, even though I specified span and result-price?

Comment: You can give use full url link in post so it will be easy to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `a.text` instead of `a.span.string`